# Android App crash only on Android 6

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

I have create a small application but this crash only on Android 6 on this line of code create by android studio in first activity drawer:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

Error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.application/com.application.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

detailed error:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
```

This app crash only on this device/android 6, with android 7 and 8 no problem, the code is correct in any way like:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

and same perfect code for xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true               
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.2'
    //implementation 'io.github.tonnyl:whatsnew:+'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.6'
    implementation "com.tonyodev.fetch2:fetch2:2.1.0-RC3"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: can you update your question with app-module's build.gradle?

Comment: Added all code of build.gradle :)

Comment: Is it working on OS < Android 6?

Comment: I have no tested with < 6 actualy i have tested only on android 6 device and emulator, with same crash, android 7 e 8 only on real device

Comment: Do you have any resources in `drawable-v24`?

Comment: Yes :) ohh whait some resources required are only v24

Comment: Yes, thanks so much!! Create answer i check with success :)

Comment: No problem. Done. You might need to refresh your page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are experiencing this issue because you have resources in `drawable-v24` only and you are trying to reference them in v23 (Android M). Either move them to `drawable` folder or `drawable-v23` (if these resources are not required in lower version)