# Error after downgrade Android API from 27 to 21 (KOTLIN)

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

I tried to downgrade my app from api 27 to 21 because my target api is from 21 to 27. But it can only run on API 26 and 27. After downgrade i try to install on API 21 then the app cannot open (it stopped working after open)

Here is my main_activity

```
package com.ddm.xposed.digi_com

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import com.felhr.usbserial.UsbSerialDevice
import com.felhr.usbserial.UsbSerialInterface
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.app_bar_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    var unlock : Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        drawer_layout.setDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        nav_view.setItemIconTintList(null);

        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        displayScreen(-1)


    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> return true
            else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    fun displayScreen(id: Int){

        val fragment = when(id){
            R.id.nav_connect -> {
                ConnectFragment()
            }

            else -> {
                ConnectFragment()
            }

        }

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativeLayout,fragment).commit()
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        displayScreen(item.itemId)

        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }


}
```

Then this is the error on debug

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.ddm.xposed.digi_com, PID: 2279
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ddm.xposed.digi_com/com.ddm.xposed.digi_com.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
>                         at com.ddm.xposed.digi_com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:32)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
>                         at com.ddm.xposed.digi_com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:32) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
>                      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f060057
>
> ```
>                   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
>                   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:756)
>                   at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:402)
>                   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
>                   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:319)
>                   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:145)
>                   at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:422)
>                   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:393)
>                   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.<init>(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:255)
>                   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:97)
>                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:149)
>                   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:88)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
>                   at com.ddm.xposed.digi_com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:32) 
>                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
>                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
> ```

Comment: have you checked my answer on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978527/android-app-crash-only-on-android-6/50982242#50982242)?

Comment: what is your compiledSdkVersion.. it should be 21. Also, all the support library versions should be 21.+

Comment: @Sagar it works! is there any explanation for this?

Comment: @RahulKumar i compiled using API 21, yes the lib also  21

Comment: I have added the explanation as answer you can check.

Comment: Well you won't be able to use API 21 compileSdk and your Target must be 26+ in about half a year so have fun with that

Answer (score 1):

Based on my answer on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978527/android-app-crash-only-on-android-6/50982242#50982242)

> You are experiencing this issue because you have resources in
>   drawable-v26 only and you are trying to reference them in v21. Either move them to drawable folder or drawable-v21 (if these
>   resources are not required in lower version)

### **Explanation:**

When you request a resource for which you provide alternatives, Android selects which alternative resource to use at runtime, depending on current device configuration.

**Lets say your current OS version is 23:**

OS tries selects drawables from `drawable-v23` by comparing the device configuration to available alternative resources.

**Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#BestMatch):**

The system arrives at its decision for which resources to use with the following logic:
The flowchart of how Android finds the best-matching resource is as follows

[image: Flowchart of how Android finds the best-matching resource.]

The precedence is based on the table defined [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#table2)

It actually works on selection by elimination. It will first eliminate `drawable-v24` and above and try to find the drawable in `drawable-v23` and below. Since it cannot find the drawables in `drawable-v23` and below it throws the exception